# Java Closure Scope

Tags: java, closures

I have the following code:

```
package application;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Application {

       public String name = "Brad" ;

       public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
              Timer time = new Timer ( );
              time.schedule ( new TimerTask ( ) {
                     @Override
                     public void run ( ) {
                            System.out.println( "Name: " ) ;
                     }
              }, 0, 10000 );

       }

}
```

how can I access methods and / or properties of the class within run () function?
honestly, I do not know how I can have access to the context .. and no idea how to pass the object as parameter, as in PHP

Comment: you cannot even access `name` within `main` at all, not just inside the closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access instance variables but in your case you can not access `name` since it is not `static`. If you want to use field variables, then you need to declare them as `final` in order to be able to use them inside an anonymous class.

Example:

```
package application; 

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Application {
  public static String name = "Brad" ;

  public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
    final String lastName = "Brad's last name";

    Timer time = new Timer ( );
    time.schedule ( new TimerTask ( ) {
      @Override
      public void run ( ) {
        System.out.println( "Name: " + name + " " + lastName ) ;
      }
    }, 0, 10000 );
  }
}
```

Comment: right, and how do I access the variable? I define it as final Application, and access using this.name?

Comment: `Like public final String name = "Brad".` The reason is, that otherwise you could reassign to the variable `name` another object, but the inner class would have a `name` to the old object. The language designers did not want that.

Comment: You have access to Application.this in general, like Application.this.name (or name).

Comment: yeah, but I see that only if the variable is static ( property `name` )

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a method in an anonymous class, the closest thing Java has to closures. You can access to Application properties or methods by invoking it like this:

```
Application.this.instanceExampleMethod();
```

or

```
Application.this.property;
```

Your case is particular though, because you are in a static method, so you'll need to modify methods to static if you want to call them (or instantiate an Application and use it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `Application` that `TimerTask` can reference. In your code there is no such instance because static methods (like `main`) don't require one. So create an instance, and declare it as final so your anonymous `TimerTask` inner class has access to it.

```
public class Application {

       private String name = "Brad" ;

       public String getName()
       {
         return name;
       }

       private void privateMethod() {}

       public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
              Timer time = new Timer ( );
              final Application application = new Application(); // instance
              time.schedule ( new TimerTask ( ) {
                     public void run ( ) {
                            System.out.println( "Name: "  + application.getName());
                            application.privateMethod(); // don't rely on this
                     }
              }, 0, 10000 );
       }
}
```

Note that in your case the `main` method is defined inside `Application`. This means that inside the `TimerTask` inner class you will have access to private (instance) fields of `Application` due to the class-level visibility in Java. In general you do not want to rely on this 'feature' and only access public methods on `Application`.